# Why do paths work locally but not on the server?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, web-hosting

I use smarterasp to host my website and database. I encountered a problem while generating a cshtml file to pdf. I don't really know how to approach this problem, because it was the first time I uploaded a website to hosting and I don't understand the paths. Has anyone encountered a similar problem and could explain how to get to the files I have locally on the server?

My code:

```
 public class PdfService : IPdfService
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public PdfService(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public byte[] GeneratePdf(Domain.Entities.Invoice invoice)
        {
            var htmlContent = GetInvoiceContent(invoice);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlContent, memoryStream);
                byte[] pdfBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return pdfBytes;
            }

        }
        private string GetInvoiceContent(Domain.Entities.Invoice invoice)
        {
            string viewName = "InvoicePdf";
            string viewPath = GetViewAbsolutePath($"Views/Invoice/{viewName}.cshtml");
            string htmlContent = RenderViewToString(viewPath, invoice);

            return htmlContent;
        }

        private string RenderViewToString(string viewPath, object model)
        {
            string viewContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(viewPath);

            string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(viewContent, viewPath, null, model);

            return result;
        }

        private string GetViewAbsolutePath(string relativePath)
        {
            string contentRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            string viewAbsolutePath = Path.Combine(contentRootPath, relativePath);
            return viewAbsolutePath;
        }
    }
```

I would like to understand how the paths work on the server, because when I go to the hosting page in the Files tab, most of the files are .dll there

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. So... what is the problem? I don't see any error information. Are you getting an exception? Where are the exception details?

Comment: @JuanR When I try to generate a pdf, I get the following error on page: Error. An error occurred while processing your request. Request ID: 00-2f7027c218971391........ Development Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred. The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.

Comment: You need to get more details about the error. The easiest way is to [enable the Developer Exception page](https://blog.elmah.io/http-error-500-30-asp-net-core-app-failed-to-start-help/). Once you collect that information, update your question if you still can't figure it out.